# New array from array with a condition …

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, slice, reduce

I want to transform:

```
a = [0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Into:

```
a2 = [
       [0.25, 0.375],
       [0.5, 0.5],
       [0.5]
     ]
```

– where the sum each row of array items <= 1

I guess some slicing, reducing treatment would do the job, but I just do not know where to insert the condition … Any help?

Comment: What have you tried so far? A simple `for` loop should do the job.

Comment: Created an array with indexes for the range, then stepped through these … which seemed overly complex, then I turned to reduce but if (acc>0) did not work …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the array by using a constraint function.

```js
const
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    constraint = sum => sum <= 1,
    array = [0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
    result = array.reduce((r, v) => {
        let last =  r[r.length - 1];
        if (!last || !constraint(last.reduce(add) + v)) r.push(last = []);
        last.push(v);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
const a = [0.25, 0.375, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5];

const result = a.reduce(
    (acc, val) => {
        const last = acc[acc.length - 1];

        if (last.reduce((a, v) => a + v, 0) + val <= 1) {
            last.push(val);
        } else {
            acc.push([val]);
        }

        return acc;
    },
    [[]],
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = 0;
var start = 0;
var a2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {
   if (s+a[i] <= 1) {
       s+=a[i];
   }
   else {
      if (i == start) {
         a2.push(a.slice(i,i);
      }
      else {
         a2.push(a.slice(start, i-1);
      }
      s = a[i]
      start = i;
   }
}
```